# Getting `help-xref-button: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (lambda ...)' when using `describe-key' with `describe-function-1' in `help+20'

Tags: help

When using `describe-key`, the following block from the `help+20` package, in the `describe-function-1` function:

```
(help-xref-button 1 #'(lambda (arg)
                      (let ((location
                         (find-function-noselect arg)))
                    (pop-to-buffer (car location))
                    (goto-char (cdr location))))
                function)
```

Is causing the following error:

```
help-xref-button: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (lambda (arg) (let ((location (find-function-noselect arg))) (pop-to-buffer (car location)) (goto-char (cdr location))))
```

I tried pulling the lambda out into its own function:

```
;;;###autoload
(defun describe-function-1--hyperlink (arg)
    (let ((location
        (find-function-noselect arg)))
  (pop-to-buffer (car location))
  (goto-char (cdr location))))
```

Modifying the `help-xref-button` call accordingly:

```
(help-xref-button 1 #'describe-function-1--hyperlink function)
```

But am getting the following error:

```
make-text-button: Unknown button type ‘describe-function-1--hyperlink’
```

How can I create a new button type, if that's what I really need to do?

Comment: IIUC, `help+20.el` is the version of the `help+.el` package that is meant for Emacs 20. Are you really running that ancient an Emacs? If not, you should probably delete the `help+20.el` package and install `help+.el`. See [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).

Comment: Ah; that makes much more sense. I didn't quite understand the difference between the two versions, as I thought that `help+20` was version 20 and above. I'll report back on whether it works later this afternoon EST!

Comment: No, I believe that `help+20.el` is for Emacs 20 *only*. `help+.el` is for Emacs 22 and later. Not sure what one should use for Emacs 21 (but I hope the question is a cademic: at this point, nobody should be using Emacs 21 IMO). See the Emacs Wiki link in my first comment.

Comment: No, no, I understand; I usually use the latest master via nix overlays. I was simply confused about versioning!  I had initially got the file from the wiki itself!

Comment: What @NickD said. The header of file [`help+20.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help%2b20.el) says: *"Extensions to `help.el' for Emacs 20"* and *"Compatibility: GNU Emacs 20.x"*.

Comment: And confirmed; thanks for all the help! I'll answer the question myself, then?

Comment: That would be fine AFAIAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) and [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) in the comments of the question, the issue was my using `help+20`, which is used only for `emacs 20`, instead of `help+`.